# Where is JShell history stored?

Tags: java, jshell

Does anybody know where JShell history is stored (Java-11/Open JDK on Windows-10, but any config might be useful)? I've been looking around in `$HOME` (`$USERPROFILE`, `$APPDATA`, ...). Is it file based?

JShell is JLine based, right? I indeed found `$JAVA_HOME\legal\jdk.internal.le\jline.md`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, the history is stored in the registry, which can be opened with regedit. The path is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\JavaSoft\Prefs\tool\/J/Shell`

Answer (score 4):

JShell uses `PreferencesStorage`, an implementation of `PersistentStorage` that is backed by a `java.util.prefs.Preferences` object. That means that the history is stored in a binary form and the location depends on the operating system. For example, on macOS you'll find the history (again, in binary form) in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.java.util.prefs.plist`.